# On the vanishing of the integral $\int^{n+4}_0 dt P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right)(-t+2)_{n+1}$ for $\ell \geq n+2$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, legendre-polynomials, pochhammer-symbol

I came across the following integral
\begin{equation}
\int^{n+4}_0 dt P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right)(-t+2)_{n+1}
\,  ,
\end{equation}
where in the above $P_{\ell}(x)$ is the Legendre polynomial, and $(x)_a$ is the Pochhammer symbol, $(x)_a = \tfrac{\Gamma(x+a)}{\Gamma(x)}$. $\ell$ is a non-negative integer number and $n$ is an integer bigger or equal to $-1$.

After running it for some values in `Mathematica` it is easy to observe that it vanishes when

- $n+\ell$ is any even number,
- $\ell \geq n+2$.

The command that defines the integral is

```
int[n_, l_] := 
 Integrate[
  LegendreP[l, 1 - (2 t)/(n + 4)] Pochhammer[-t + 2, n + 1], {t, 0, 
   n + 4}]
```

and then two examples for $n=-1$ and $n=0$

```
Table[int[-1, l], {l, 0, 5}] // FunctionExpand
Table[int[0, l], {l, 0, 5}] // FunctionExpand
```

and of course, more values can be checked in a straightforward manner.

I managed to prove that the integral yields $0$ when $n+\ell$ is equal to any even number, however, I have not managed to derive a proof that the integral vanishes for $\ell \geq n+2$.

**I was wondering if there are any suggestions on how to prove that the integral, also, vanishes for $\ell \geq n+2$.**

The proof I managed that shows the integral being equal to $0$ when $n + \ell$ is any even number is as follows:

- make the substitution
  \begin{equation*}
  t = -t^{\prime}+n+4  
  \, ,
  \end{equation*}
- use the identity $P_{\ell}(-x) = (-1)^{\ell}P_{\ell}(x)$ in order to re-write
  \begin{equation}
  P_{\ell}\left(-1 + \frac{2t^{\prime}}{n+4}\right) = P_{\ell}\left(- \left(1 - \frac{2t^{\prime}}{n+4}\right) \right) = (-1)^{\ell} P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t^{\prime}}{n+4}\right)   
  \end{equation}
- we can use $(-x)_m = (-1)^m (x-m+1)_m$ in order to re-express the Pochhammer as
  \begin{equation}
  (2+t^{\prime}-n-4)_{n+1} = (-2 + t^{\prime} -n)_{n+1} = (-1)^{n+1} (-t^{\prime}+2)_{n+1}    
  \end{equation}

Having all the above, we can express the original integral in terms of the $t^{\prime}$ variable in the following manner:
\begin{equation}
\int^0_{n+4} - dt^{\prime} (-1)^{\ell} P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t^{\prime}}{n+4}\right) (-1)^{n+1} (-t^{\prime}+2)_{n+1}
\end{equation}
and we can now swap the integration limits in the above to get
\begin{equation}
(-1)^{1+n+\ell} \int^{n+4}_0 dt^{\prime} P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t^{\prime}}{n+4}\right)
(-t^{\prime}+2)_{n+1}  
\, .
\end{equation}
In the above we rename $t^{\prime} \rightarrow t$ and get
\begin{equation}\label{eq: integral_aux_02}
(-1)^{1+n+\ell} \int^{n+4}_0 dt  P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right)(-t+2)_{n+1}   \, .
\end{equation}
So, what we have obtained so far is the following:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
          &\int^{n+4}_0 dt P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right)(-t+2)_{n+1} = \\
(-1)^{1+n+\ell}       &\int^{n+4}_0 dt  P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right) (-t+2)_{n+1} \Rightarrow  
\\
\left(1 - (-1)^{1+n+\ell}  \right)  &\int^{n+4}_0 dt P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right)(-t+2)_{n+1} = 0 \Rightarrow
\\
\left(1 + (-1)^{n+\ell}   \right)  &\int^{n+4}_0 dt P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right)(-t+2)_{n+1} = 0  
\, ,
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
but for $n+\ell$ an even number $\left(1 + (-1)^{n+\ell}   \right) =2$ and hence
\begin{equation}
\int^{n+4}_0 dt P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right)(-t+2)_{n+1} = 0  
\, .
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that if $\ell\ge n+2$, then
$$\int_0^{n+4} dt P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right)(-t+2)_{n+1}=0$$

*Proof* :

Using
$$P_{\ell}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{\ell+k}{k}\bigg(\frac{x-1}{2}\bigg)^k$$
(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Rodrigues%27_formula_and_other_explicit_formulas)), we have

$$\begin{align}&\int_{0}^{n+4} dt P_{\ell}\left(1 - \frac{2t}{n+4}\right)(-t+2)_{n+1}
\\\\&=\int_{0}^{n+4}dt\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{\ell+k}{k}\bigg(-\frac{t}{n+4}\bigg)^k(-t+2)(-t+3)\cdots (-t+n+2)
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{\ell+k}{k}\bigg(-\frac{1}{n+4}\bigg)^k\int_{0}^{n+4}t^k(-t+2)(-t+3)\cdots (-t+n+2)dt\tag1\end{align}$$
Let $a_j$ be the coefficient of $t^j$ in $(-t+2)(-t+3)\cdots (-t+n+2)$.

Then, $(1)$ can be written as
$$\begin{align}(1)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{\ell+k}{k}\bigg(-\frac{1}{n+4}\bigg)^k\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\frac{a_j(n+4)^{k+j+1}}{k+j+1}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{\ell+k}{k}(-1)^k\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\frac{a_j(n+4)^{j+1}}{k+j+1}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}a_j(n+4)^{j+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{\ell+k}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+j+1}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}a_j(n+4)^{j+1}G(\ell,j)\tag2\end{align}$$

where
$$G(\ell,j):=\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{\ell+k}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+j+1}$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28C%28l%2Ck%29%29*%28C%28l%2Bk%2Ck%29%29*%28%28-1%29%5Ek%29%2F%28k%2Bj%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cl%7D%5D) says
$$G(\ell,j)=\frac{j!(\ell-j-1)!}{(-j-1)!(\ell+j+1)!}$$
which can be written as
$$G(\ell,j)=\frac{\binom{\ell}{\ell+j+1}}{\ell \binom{\ell-1}{j}}$$

So, if $\ell\ge n+2$, then $G(\ell,j)=0$ for every $j=0,1,\cdots, n+1$.

Therefore, we have $(2)=0$.$\ \blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed answer. I really appreciate it. Of course, it's a (+1) from me, I am just going to wait a bit with the accept in case another one appears. Nicely done!!!

Comment: I was wondering if you could explain a little bit how you re-wrote the integral in equation (1) as a truncated summation afterwards, because I cannot figure it out. Many thanks in advance for this!

Comment: @a_User_with_No_namE : The integral can be written as $$\int_0^{n+4}t^k\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}a_jt^j\ dt=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}a_j\int_0^{n+4}t^{k+j}dt=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\frac{a_j(n+4)^{k+j+1}}{k+j+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I was blind to something simple and straightforward. Kudos again for the wonderful answer!

Comment: I have another question in case you have the time: when computing $G(\ell,j)$ we get the correct zeroes but, everything else appears to be indeterminate. For example, even if you evaluate tables for different values of $\ell$ and $j$ without specifying $\ell = n+2$ the only non-zero results are the ones that are indeterminate, see for instance [wolfram result][1]


  [1]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BTable%5B%28j%21%20%28-1%20-%20j%20%2B%20l%29%21%29%2F%28%28-1%20-%20j%29%21%20%281%20%2B%20j%20%2B%20l%29%21%29%2C%7Bl%2C0%2C16%2C1%7D%5D%2C%7Bj%2C0%2C16%2C1%7D%5D

Comment: @a_User_with_No_namE : I'm not sure if I understand your comment, but I think you can directly prove that $G(\ell,j)=0$ for $0\le j\le n+1$ using the idea of [this beautiful answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1907121/78967).

Comment: Perhaps I did not phrase myself properly. The original integral is zero for $\ell \geq n+2$. If you choose, say, $\ell = n+1$ the integral is non-zero. However, if you evaluate $G(n+1,j)$ for $j=0,\ldots,n+1$ the result is $0$, see [mathematica screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrqXf.png). This is what seems problematic to me. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @a_User_with_No_namE : It is not true that $G(n+1,n+1)=0$ because the denominator of $\dfrac{\binom{\ell}{\ell+j+1}}{\ell \binom{\ell-1}{j}}$ is $0$ when $\ell-1\lt j$.

Comment: Right. It turns out that I need to consider the limit so that `Mathematica` can return the correct values, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsyXI.png). Thanks for helping me clarify this!