# Re-writing a sum of binomial coefficients as an integral of shifted Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, binomial-coefficients, legendre-polynomials

This is a question regarding the [answer presented here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904656/evaluate-sum-limits-k-0n-1nkn-choose-k-nk-choose-n-frac1k/1904738#1904738).

In order to make this post self-contained, I am wondering if someone can explain why the sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n+k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\frac{1}{k+2} \tag{1}
$$
can be re-written as
$$
\int_{0}^{1}x\, Q_n(x)\,dx \tag{2}
$$
where in the above $Q_n(x)$ is the shifted Legendre polynomial that satisfy
$$ 
Q_n(x)=P_n(2x-1)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n+k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}x^k \tag{3}
$$
with $P_n(x)$ the ordinary Legendre polynomials.

I am aware of how to re-write a sum as an integral, but I have never encountered an example of the form of eq.(1) and I find passing from eq.(1) to eq.(2) a bit confusing.

Comment: Simply perform term-wise integration by swapping the integral and the finite sum, and just use the fact that with $k\geq 0$, $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+1}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{x^{k+2}}{k+2}\bigg]_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{k+2}.$$ That’s all there is to it.

Comment: @KStarGamer thanks for the comment, however, that was not my issue. I guess what I wrote was not clear enough. I was able to go from eq.(2) to eq.(1) without issues, which is what you explained. My question was how to go from eq.(1) to eq.(2) directly. Is this clearer now?

Comment: I’m unsure why you cannot just reverse the process. Write $\frac{1}{k+2}$ as $\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$ and once again swap the integral and finite sum.

Comment: @KStarGamer yes, thanks for pointing this out. It was only after I wrote my comment that I realized your hint!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)